# Proving partial order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, order-theory

In few days I'm having an exam from Formal Logic and Set Theory and would like to confirm if my method of proving partial orders is correct. The task:

*For $(n, m), (p, q) \in \mathbb{N}_{+}^{2}$, $$(n, m) \preceq (p, q) \Leftrightarrow (n, m) = (p, q) \vee (n < p \wedge n - m \leq p - q).$$ Prove that $\preceq$ is a partial order.*

Here is my idea for the proof:

**1) Reflexive**

(a, b) $ \preceq $ (a, b)

$(a, b) = (a, b) \vee (a < a \wedge (a - b) \leq (a - b))$

The first part is true, so it's reflexive.

**2) Antisymmetric**

$ (a, b) \preceq (c, d) \wedge (c, d) \preceq (a, b) \Rightarrow (a, b) = (c, d) $

My idea was to write above condition using actual rules given in the task:

$ [(a, b) = (c, d) \vee ((a < c) \wedge (a - b) \leq (c - d))] \wedge [(c, d) = (a, b) \vee ((c < a) \wedge (c - d) \leq (a - b))] $

If we mark every part in brackets divided with $ \vee $ with letters p, q, r, s, we can see that distribution of p and r will give us:

$ [(a, b) = (c, d) \wedge (c, d) = (a, b))] $

And that's what we were looking for. So antisymmetry is true.

**3) Transitive**

$ (a, b) \preceq (c, d) \wedge (c, d) \preceq (e, f) \Rightarrow (a, b) \preceq (e, f) $

I used the similar procedure to what I did above. Mainly I wrote the conditions:

$ [(a, b) = (c, d) \vee ((a < c) \wedge (a - b) \leq (c - d))] \wedge [(c, d) = (e, f) \vee ((c < e) \wedge (c - d) \leq (e - f))] $

I once again used p, q, r, s notation and distributed. Again, distribution of p and r gives us:

$ [(a, b) = (c, d) \wedge (c, d) = (e, f)] $

Which should prove the last part, because that's the condition of partial order in the task. Is that the correct way of proving partial orders? I will be very thankful for tips and answers, because they will help me pass the course.

Comment: I haven't read the details of your proof but your approach is correct. You use the definition of your relation to show that it has the properties of a partial order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a different approach in your proofs of anti-symmetry and transitivity.
This way, you don't need distribution.

**Anti-symmetry.**
The second branch of the definitions doesn't apply, since that would include $a<c$ and $c<a$, a contradiction.
Thus, you get immediatelly $(a,b) = (c,d)$ (by definition), which is what was to be proven.

**Transitivity.**
It's a similar situation.
If $(a,b) = (c,d)$, then $(a,b) \leq (e,f)$ because $(c,d) \leq (e,f)$;
the same happens if $(c,d) = (e,f)$.
So the only non-trivial situation is if
$$a<c<e$$
and
$$a-b < c-d < e-f,$$
from which it follows that $a < e$ and $a-b< e-f$ (it turns out to be rather trivial too).

Comment: Thank you! Now it seems understandable and kinda easy. I will definitely use your approach in the future, but was my also correct?

Comment: @Miszka Your approach is correct, but a little bit confusing. You skip passages which some may hand-waive, but it is not certain. In this case, we have a shortcut.

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot for your help. It answers my question, I will try to look for such shortcuts as you have shown above in the future.